# Capturing time between HTML form submit action and printing response

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a Python Flask application with a HTML form which accept few inputs from user, uses those in an python program which returns the processed values back to flask application return statement.

I wanted to capture the time took for whole processing and rendering output data on browser but not sure how to do that. At present I have captured the take by python program to process the input values but it doesn't account for complete time between "submit" action and rendering output data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) WebAPI

As per the documentation,

It starts a timer you can use to track how long an operation takes. You give each timer a unique name, and may have up to 10,000 timers running on a given page. When you call console.timeEnd() with the same name, the browser will output the time, in milliseconds, that elapsed since the timer was started.

To start the timer, you need to write,

```
console.start('some_function_name');
```

To end the timer after page rendering,

```
console.timeEnd('some_function_name');
```

while will output you the total time taken between your submit action and the printing response.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax request to submit form. Fetch the time on clicking the button and after getting the response and then calculate the difference.